# Return HTML content as a string, given URL Javascript/Jquery Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get a link's URL from a web page and add to my code. The search can be based on link's `<a>` tag content because I also have no id for that link. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you explain more? and perhaps, post your attempt?

Comment: Sure there is. What have *you* tried so far? Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: Please clarify your question. I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Please refer to our [ask] page to help you improve this question.  Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: Please don't ask "give me teh codez" questions, show what you have tried and how it didn't work

Comment: Post some code exactly what you going to do. This will help you to get the appropriate answer. [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: I have a URL for example "https://example.com/index.htm" and there is a pdf href# link in  <a> tag that I wanted to fetch and I don't have any id for these <a> tags in "https://example.com/index.htm", I only have the content <a> content </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the question is "How can I get the URL (href property) of a link in the page using the tag content ( the content between <a> & </a> ) ".

You can use something like this:

```
function getLinkByTagContent(tagContent) { 
    var docLink; 
    for(var ii = 0; ii < document.links.length ; ii++) { 
        docLink = document.links[ii]
        if( docLink.text === tagContent ) {
            return docLink.href; 
        }
    } 
}
```